# VBA Selenium Chrome Unexpected Alert Error

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently using Selenium, VBA Excel, and Chrome to scrape information from a site.  Everything works fine until one of the values from my list is not available on the site, then I get a **Run-time error '26' UnexpectedAlertOpenError**. [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFsgl.png).

I have added this line **Chrome.SwitchToAlert(5).accept** to handle the error which works when the value is not available.  Unfortunately, adding that line returns a **Run-Time error '27' NoAlertPresentError** when the value from the list is available. [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dNwJ.png).

The error messages make sense, can't act on what is not there. I need a way to check if there is an alert and if so then quit chrome, else run the rest of the code.  I have tried `If Chrome.FindElementsByTag("tr") Is Nothing Then Chrome.SwitchToAlert(5).accept else`  and `If Chrome.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'Details')]").Count > 0 Then` and other things but nothing seems to work to address the error 26.

Answer (score 0):

Well so based on the VBA selenium library I checked apparently there is no way of checking a count of the alerts already displayed, something we could do for browser windows by using:

```
driver.Windows.Count 'driver being the variable used to refer to an instance of Chromedriver
```

So the solution I am using is of wrapping the entire selenium code between error handlers:

```
On Error Goto Problem:
' Your code over here
''''''
''''''
On Error Goto 0

Exit Sub
Problem:
    If InStr(1, Err.Description, "Alert") <> 0 Then
        driver.SwitchToAlert.accept 'could also use: driver.SwitchToAlert.dismiss
        Resume Next 'resumes code from the next line in code that threw error
    End If
```

This way I believe whenever any sudden unexpected alert pops up, the error handler will accept/dismiss the alert and with 'Resume Next' ensure program moves on from the next line